# Compile error while using sqlite3: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I get a compilation error in the code below when I try to declare a sqlite3 object. Is "database" not an object type? Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface BasicDao : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) sqlite3 *database;  //error : Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

@end
```

Answer (score 8):

`sqlite3 *database` is not a pointer to an Objective-C object but a C pointer to the [`struct sqlite3`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/sqlite3.html). You cannot `retain`/`release` it since the memory is not managed by the Objective-C run-time. Use `assign` instead of `retain`.

Comment: so we don`t need to do any memory management with "database" or this kind of thing?

Comment: You need to manage the memory yourself with these non-Objective-C allocated memory in the typical C way. Find an appropriate place (usually in `dealloc`) to do the cleanup work for SQLite API.